# Convert Varchar with Nulls to Date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, varchar

I have a table with a VARCHAR column of dates in the following format: `2005-02-17 00:00:00`. Some of the rows contain a date such as the one listed above, and the others are `NULL`.

How can I convert the whole column to the DATE format so that I can compare with other dates. My end goal is to create a flag that is 1 if the date in my `VARCHAR` column is between 1-1-2014 and 3-31-2014 (i.e.  `between to_date('01/01/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('03/31/2014','mm/dd/yyyy')`).

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose that `to_date(NULL,'mm/dd/yyyy')` yields `NULL`. What do you want instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `to_date` on a `null` value will just return `null`, which ins't between any two values, so you can just ignore this case:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
              TO_DATE(my_varchar, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
              BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') AND 
                       TO_DATE('03/31/2014 23:59:59','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS flag
FROM    my_table
```

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar ah! Now, after the edit, I see what you're getting at. But that's a pretty clunky way of doing it, and not **at all** sure that was what the OP was gunning for.

Comment: Agreed , for this few go with `>= date1 and < date2+1`

Comment: This works for me. You're correct, I only cared about finding the columns that fit in my range, so the fact that to_date returns NULL for NULL values is great. I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

simplest approach create a view with

```
SELECT  NVL(my_dates, '1900-01-01 00:00:00')
```

and operate on that